# Spark : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq$ofRef

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to run a simple word count program with `spark-submit` and getting an exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>       scala/collection/mutable/ArraySeq$ofRef
>           at SparkWordCount$.main(SparkWordCount.scala:18)

The code, starting with line 18 is

```
val count = input.flatMap(line ⇒ line.split(" "))
    .map(word ⇒ (word, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

My environment:

- Windows 10
- java version "1.8.0_221"
- spark-shell shows : Spark version 2.4.4 (Using Scala version 2.11.12)
- scala -version command shows
  *Scala code runner version 2.13.1*

Comment: 2.11 and 2.13 are not compatible, but `scala -version` isn't necessarily relevant. If you have `build.sbt` file, what does it look like?

Comment: Oh ok, got it. I don't use build.sbt. I removed system Scala (v 2.13.1) and installed Scala v 2.11 with scala-2.11.12.msi.
Now I compile with Scala 2.11.12 and spark-submit to Spark 2.4.4 which is using Scala 2.11.12.

Now the program runs.

Comment: @user1575148 I would recommend you to use **SBT** manually compiling a project will be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the solution is to use for development the same version of Scala that you will use on the cluster.